# Database connectivity in java using odbc-: can't find microsoft access driver (*.mdb *.accdb) option

Tags: java, odbc, ms-access-2007

I am trying to connect MS office access with my java code using odbc driver.

Precisely, In **ODBC data source Administrator**, as I click the add button, the **Create New Data Source** dialog box appears.

But I can't find the  **Microsoft access driver (*.mdb *.accdb)** option.

There is only one option named SQL Server. My problem is shown in the image given below. I am using Windows 7. Where is this **Microsoft access driver (*.mdb *.accdb)** option?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, I'd say you're hitting a bitness mismatch between your ODBC driver and your ODBC client (Java, in this case) on 64-bit Wndows.  See [this article for some basics about that](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin).

Most commonly for what you've shown, you're probably running a 32-bit Java on 64-bit Windows 7, where you have a 32-bit ODBC Driver for SQL Server (seen in the Drivers list) and a 64-bit ODBC Driver for MS Access (used by the User DSNs seen in the Administrator window behind).

- If you want to stick with the installed (or newer, through Java 7) 32-bit Java, you'll need to download and install 32-bit data access components for the right version of MS Access (this link will get you [components for MS Access 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)).
- If you update to a 32-bit Java 8 or later, you'll need to download and install 32-bit data access components for the right version of MS Access (this link will get you [components for MS Access 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)), and you'll need to also add a third-party JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge (like [this from my employer](https://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/)).
- If you switch to a 64-bit Java 7 or earlier (which retains the Sun/Oracle JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge), you can use the existing 64-bit ODBC Driver for Access.
- If you switch to a 64-bit Java 8 or later, you can use the existing 64-bit ODBC Driver for Access, but you'll need to also add a third-party JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge (like [this from my employer](https://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/)).

That said -- you *might* be running running a 64-bit Java on 64-bit Windows 7, where you have a 64-bit ODBC Driver for SQL Server (seen in the Drivers list) and a 32-bit ODBC Driver for MS Access (used by the User DSNs seen in the Administrator window behind).

- If you want to stick with the installed (or newer, through Java 7) 64-bit Java, you'll need to download and install 64-bit data access components for the right version of MS Access (this link will get you [components for MS Access 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)).
- If you update to a 64-bit Java 8 or later, you'll need to download and install 64-bit data access components for the right version of MS Access (this link will get you [components for MS Access 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)), and you'll need to also add a third-party JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge (like [this from my employer](https://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/)).
- If you switch to a 32-bit Java 7 or earlier (which retains the Sun/Oracle JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge), you can use the existing 32-bit ODBC Driver for Access.
- If you switch to a 32-bit Java 8 or later, you can use the existing 32-bit ODBC Driver for Access, but you'll need to also add a third-party JDBC-to-ODBC Bridge (like [this from my employer](https://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/)).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft stopped shipping the driver with Windows. If you don't have Access installed, you probably don't have the database driver.

You can download the [Microsoft Access Database Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) here, which will allow you to open Access files.